# BeautifulSoup 4 Install Error by typing pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, failed-installation

I tried to install BeautifulSoup 4

It worked after I typed following into my mac terminal

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup4
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

But when I imported it in my python,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

the screen always shows the Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
```

Then I googled the error and found by typing following code in terminal could solve the problem

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

But after I typed,it was shown 
Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 324, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py'
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks for someone help

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l //anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to solve this is using Sudo.

```
    sudo pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

However sudo is not always recommended to do so, you should not install arbitrary code as root.

My recommendation would be to create a virtualenv, install the packages play with before using sudo to install them as root.

You can use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv
workon
python setup.py install
```